# iOS expand UITableViewCell on click with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I'm working on simple application and now I'm focused on expanding UITableViewCell after user tap that cell. It's iOS 8 app so I have set:

```
self.tableVIew.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
self.tableVIew.estimatedRowHeight = 50
```

cell constraints look like this:

[image]

If user tap cell this function is called:

```
func extend() {
        self.contentView.removeConstraint(self.bottomConstraint)

        let additionalView = UIView()
        additionalView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        additionalView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
        self.contentView.addSubview(additionalView)
        self.contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[additionalView(50)]-5-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["additionalView" : additionalView]))
        self.contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-5-[additionalView(100)]-5@999-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["additionalView" : additionalView]))
    }
```

self.bottomConstraint is costraint between green circle bottom and cell contentView bottom.

The question is:
Why this solution works **only** if there is priority set in constraint:

```
V:|-5-[additionalView(100)]-5@999-|
```

?

Without explicit priority I got errors:

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a63f7a0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7a737840(60)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a644f40 V:|-(5)-[UIView:0x7a63f2a0]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7a737840 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a644fb0 V:[UIView:0x7a63f2a0(100)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a644f70 V:[UIView:0x7a63f2a0]-(5)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7a737840 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a644f70 V:[UIView:0x7a63f2a0]-(5)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7a737840 )>
```

Comment: My guess is that your current cell height is 60 and new height is 110, so it need to break one of the constraint to make it grow, default priority is 1000, 3 equal priority constraints need one to be broken.

Comment: Height of cell shouldn't be computed dynamically based on content view constraints?

Comment: Yes, but additionalView has a height 100, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is. Maybe I not getting it in right way, but if I add view with height of 100 with constraints to superview, the cell should recalculate it's height and there is no reason to not satisfy any constraints.

Comment: Yes, it should, you can use layoutIfNeeded to test more.

Comment: I have tried this but it's not working :)

Answer (score 2):

I have made a demo that gives you the exact behaviour as you want.
here is the link: 
https://github.com/rushisangani/TableViewCellExpand

Please set constraint of your expand/ collapse views as described in demo.

Comment: Thanks for this. I know I can set priority to 999 and It will work but in my opinion it is a hack.

Comment: @MichalMoskala setting a priority to 999 is not hack!

Comment: one more thing to mention Inner bounding constraints of detail view must have lower priority than heght of detailview

Comment: Your project saved my life! This is exactly the type of simple answer I needed!! Not an over-engineered cocoa pod, just something clean and straight to the point.

Answer (score 0):

`'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height'` is the constraint for the row height created after the table view system has calculated what it should be. Simply changing the constraint inside isn't enough to force recalculation.

This isn't new unexpected behavior; while effects could sometimes be achieved by letting cells hang out of their tableview-supplied height, the table view data source delegate is meant to provide the "official" row height.

Apple's sample project [Table View Animations and Gestures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Listings/TVAnimationsGestures_APLTableViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010139-TVAnimationsGestures_APLTableViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_19) is illustrative. It hasn't been updated for iOS 8's self-sizing cells but it's worth a look regardless. In the [APLTableViewController.m](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Listings/TVAnimationsGestures_APLTableViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010139-TVAnimationsGestures_APLTableViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_19) the tableViewController is the delegate for the cell's pitch gesture, because it needs to adjust the height. Its `handlePinch:` calls `updateForPinchScale: atIndexPath:` which does the expansion like you want.

The Table View Controller doesn't try to change the row height directly.  First, it sets its own custom data source object (called sectionInfo) to provide an updated value for the row height `[sectionInfo replaceObjectInRowHeightsAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@(newHeight)];`
. Then the Table View Controller does the following:

```
BOOL animationsEnabled = [UIView areAnimationsEnabled];
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:animationsEnabled];
```

Turning off all UIView animations is because this is a pinch, so it should change instantly without jerkyness. Since you only want a one-time change, you should experiment with different animation settings to get the effect you want.

They key is the pair of `beginUpdates` / `endUpdates` calls that apparently triggers the system to recalculate the row heights. It's possible that with the new iOS self-sizing cells, simply changing the constraints and calling these methods might be enough; you could also try sandwiching `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone`

Comment: I'm calling beginUpdates / endUpdates like this:
`func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  
  let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as TableViewCell
  
  cell.extend()
  tableView.beginUpdates()
  tableView.endUpdates()
 }`
and layout is correct but I'm getting error as described in first post.

Answer (score -2):

set the height priority of one of your views to 999 instead 1000.